# *Novice trying to learn Quiz app* trouble storing and showing the score in another activity

Tags: java, android

Been searching the whole world wide web and haven't been able to find a solution to get this to work.

There is 15 questions in total.

Each question include an audio clip, and you get 4 buttons choices.
3 wrong choices which will give you + 0 score.
1 right choice which give you + 1 score.

after you finished all 15 questions you can click "Show score"
And here I want to make a TextView which shows you how many questions out of 15 you got right.

It sounds pretty simple to make this to work, 
But I've tried multiple codes with SharedPreferences, Editors, Arrays etc...
First sample code is from pressing the right answer on the first question.
Second sample code is for the show score after finishing the quiz.

```
 final Button answerC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerC);
    answerC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mresult", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("result", + 1);
            editor.apply();
```

---

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy_result);


    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mResult", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int myResult = prefs.getInt("result", 0);
```

Comment: Whats the problem with the code you provided ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to send data from one Activity to another Activity you have a few options depending on your circumstances. Although, for my answer - I'm going to assume that it's easy for you to navigate to another activity at a moments notice.

With what you're doing, you must understand that data in activities are completely mutable and can be voided by androids garbage collection at any time - you must develop your applications with this in mind and not rely on data constantly being available within your classes.

With the little information you've provided it seems as if you have a main activity in which you're storing data about the user's score and you want to change the user's activity and display that on the other screen.

I would advise that you create a Score object of some sort and allow it to implement the interface Serializable

You can then simply write the following to start the other activity

```
Intent toShowScoreActivity = new Intent(currentActivity, ShowScoreActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Score score = new Score(1);
bundle.putSerializable("score", scoreSerialized);
toShowScoreActivity.putExtras(bundle);
activity.startActivity(toShowScoreActivity);
```

then, when the other activity is started, you can reference the Serialized Score object by doing the following:

```
Score score = (Score) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("score")
```

Here's the mock up, over simplified, Score.java

```
package Testing;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Score implements Serializable {

    private final int score;

    public Score(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

I would definitely recommend reading up more about android's guide to app architecture and conventional management of the Activity life cycle over at the following links
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide
- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
- https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.app.Activity&method=getIntent